# How long does it take to allocate an array (in Java)

Tags: java, arrays

Just a general question about array allocation, primarily in Java but I imagine it is relevant to all programming languages:

How long does it take to allocate memory for an array of size n [in terms of O(n)]? I could imagine an implementation where the memory allocation happens in constant time: if you have a large quantity of empty memory you could just create a pointer to the first and last index of the new array, but is that how the memory is generally allocated? (Also, at least in Java, if you initialize an array of integers, all of the values in the array with be initially set to 0; does that mean that each of the indices in the array are individually set to equal 0, which would make the operation O(n)?)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you attempt to benchmark it yourself?

Comment: Being open-ended as it is, I think that this question would be better asked on Programmers.

Comment: @devnull he's asking about asymptotic efficiency not temporal efficiency.  Don't know how you could benchmark that...

Comment: @devnull On that note, assylias' answer using benchmarking does provide some nice insight.

Comment: It would also be interesting to see how the benchmark varies with the JDK version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just ran a [micro benchmark](https://bitbucket.org/assylias/performance/src/4bd1457f1432c85fc294b3636d797d276021d2c4/src/main/java/com/assylias/performance/ArrayVsList.java?at=master) on hotspot - post JIT compilation, allocating an array (on an i7) takes:

- around 10 ns for an array of size 1
- around 400 ns for an array of size 10,000
- around 300,000 ns for an array of size 1,000,000

So to answer your question, **it seems empirically that it is O(n) on hotspot**.

Detailed results:

```
Benchmark                              Mode Thr    Cnt  Sec         Mean   Mean error    Units
c.a.p.ArrayVsList.createArray1         avgt   1      5    2       12.293        0.867  nsec/op
c.a.p.ArrayVsList.createArray10000     avgt   1      5    2      428.369        9.997  nsec/op
c.a.p.ArrayVsList.createArray1M        avgt   1      5    2   342972.975     7253.989  nsec/op
```

- creating an object in java, if your heap is large enough, is almost free (it roughly consists in offsetting a pointer)
- but the JVM seems to eagerly initialise all the items to `null` (or 0 for a primitive) at the time the array is created
- other JVMs might perform a lazier initialization

Comment: It would be interesting to see how fast a larger array would be allocated. My original question was about O(n), but I imagine that the amortized complexity should be somewhat correlated with the actual running time.

Comment: That would seem to be a reasonable explanation given the empirical data, and lejlot's example with the byte code appears to confirm it.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 as usual, thorough and scientific. It might be interesting to add the timing for an array of size zero, which would empirically show the overhead for setting up the array (before allocating memory for element references)

Comment: @Bohemian There is no noticeable difference between 0 and 1 (setting one Integer to null probably takes a couple of instructions, so sub nanosecond stuff). One issue with the benchmark is that it is not adjusted for GC time (there is a lot more GC at size 1M than at size 1). It does not seem to affect the general result though (around 5% spent in GC in the worst case AFAICT).

Comment: You could always hold all references so there's no GC.

Comment: @Bohemian more than 10k 1M arrays are created during each test - that wouldn't fit in my 2GB heap... But looking at the GC log, I have about 0.1 sec of minor GCs per 2 second run. So not too bad it seems.

Answer (score 3):

You have already answered the question by yourself, it is `O(n)` in Java since elements are initialized, while there are languages where this operation is `O(1)` since there is no initialization.

and just to be sure

```
public class ArrayTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] var = new int[5];
  }

}
```

produces

```
public class ArrayTest extends java.lang.Object{
public ArrayTest();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_5
   1:   newarray int
   3:   astore_1
   4:   return

}
```

and documentation says about **newarray**:

> A new array whose components are of type atype and of length count is
>   allocated from the garbage-collected heap. A reference arrayref to
>   this new array object is pushed into the operand stack. **Each** of the
>   elements of the new array is **initialized to the default initial value**
>   for the type of the array (§2.5.1).

Comment: Not necessarily - the only guarantee is that when you first access an array item, it must have a value of 0 - nothing says that it has to be done at initialisation time.

Comment: it shows that the internal function **newarray** is invoked, which is documented with information regarding initialization of the elements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html

Comment: Spec wording is not implemented literally. The bytecode is as telling as the Java code with regards to what happens.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, array allocation is always O(n) up to the maximum size you can have.  This is because the cost of zeroing out the memory is O(n) as well.  There are some tricks the system can do to make this faster. i.e. It doesn't have to zero out every byte, it can zero out whole pages using some virtual memory tricks, but even so this is O(n) as well.